# Is there any way we can parse s string expression in Apache Flink Table API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to perform aggregation using Flink Table API by accepting group by field and field aggregation expressions as string parameters from the user.

Input

- GroupBy Field = department
- aggregation Field Expression = `count(employeeId)`, `max(salary)`

Is there any way we can do it using flink Table API? I tried to do the following, but it didn't help. Does flink have anything equivalent to `selectExpr` function in spark?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html

```
employeeTable
      .groupBy($("department"))
      .select(
        $("department"),
        $("count(employeeId)").as("numberOfEmployees"),
        $("max(salary)").as("maxSalary")
      )
```

It is throwing the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot resolve field [count(employeeId)], input field list:[department].
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe this will work. Flink's SQL planner wants to know what the query is doing at compile time.

What you can do is construct a SQL query and create a new job to run that query. The SQL gateway that's coming in Flink 1.16 (see [FLIP-91](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/rIyMC)) should make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong syntax.

```
  .select(
    $("department"),
    $("count(employeeId)").as("numberOfEmployees"),
    $("max(salary)").as("maxSalary")
  )
```

**count** and **max** you should call like this :

```
  $("employeeId").count().as("numberOfEmployees"),
  $("salary").max().as("maxSalary")
```

You can check Built-in functions [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/)

Comment: Hi Niko, i am aware of this syntax. I was trying to see whether the user can enter a string like how they enter the select clause in a SQL statement and get it evaluated using FLINK API similar to how Spark does it here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr.html

Comment: Hi @tpuli. Maybe that's what you ask for -> [link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/overview/#queries). You can write query like this `tableEnv.sqlQuery(
  "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM " + table + " WHERE product LIKE '%Rubber%'");`

Comment: I found this that helped parse the expression. But it seems to be deprecated in Flink 15. NOt sure what is the replacement!

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/expressions/ExpressionParser.html